# beamer cambridgeus theme - title color

Tags: beamer

How to make the title color in the beamer cambrigeus theme as red. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\title[Semantic Web ranking]{Ranking of Web Documents using Semantic Similarity}
\author{Subham Soni}
\date{19.8.2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color of the title by

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=green}
```

However for me the example produces a red title.